Next js 14 & Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server
I have a problem, which is that when I was dismantling the front-end project of aave, there was a Link component that nested another layer of NextLink inside, causing the project to report an error, Expected server HTML to contain a matching<a>in<a>. This is my code
const Anchor = styled('a')({});

export const NextLinkComposed = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLAnchorElement,
  NextLinkComposedProps
>(function NextLinkComposed(props, ref) {
  const {
    to,
    linkAs,
    href,
    replace,
    scroll,
    shallow,
    prefetch,
    locale,
    ...other
  } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <NextLink
        href={to}
        prefetch={prefetch}
        as={linkAs}
        replace={replace}
        scroll={scroll}
        shallow={shallow}
        passHref
        locale={locale}
        
     >
        <Anchor ref={ref} {...other} />
      </NextLink>
    </div>
  );
});

export type LinkProps = {
  as?: NextLinkProps['as'];
  href: NextLinkProps['href'];
  linkAs?: NextLinkProps['as']; // Useful when the as prop is shallow by styled().
  noLinkStyle?: boolean;
} & Omit<NextLinkComposedProps, 'to' | 'linkAs' | 'href'> &
  Omit<MuiLinkProps, 'href'>;

// A styled version of the Next.js Link component:
// https://nextjs.org/docs/#with-link
export const Link = React.forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, LinkProps>(
  function Link(props, ref) {
    const {
      as: linkAs,
      className: classNameProps,
      href,
      noLinkStyle,
      role, // Link don't have roles.
      ...other
    } = props;

    const isExternal =
      typeof href === 'string' &&
      (href.indexOf('http') === 0 || href.indexOf('mailto:') === 0);

    const router = useRouter();
    const pathname = typeof href === 'string' ? href : href.pathname;
    const className = clsx(classNameProps, {
      active: router?.pathname === pathname,
    });
    if (isExternal) {
      if (noLinkStyle) {
        return (
          <Anchor
            className={className}
            href={href}
            ref={ref}
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener"
            underline="none"
            {...other}
          />
        );
      }

      return (
        <MuiLink
          className={className}
          href={href}
          ref={ref}
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener"
          underline="none"
          {...other}
        />
      );
    }

    if (noLinkStyle) {
      return (
        <NextLinkComposed
          className={className}
          ref={ref}
          to={href}
          underline="none"
          {...other}
        />
      );
    }

    return (
      <MuiLink
        component={NextLinkComposed}
        linkAs={linkAs}
        className={className}
        ref={ref}
        to={href}
        underline="none"
        {...other}
      />
    );
  },
);

The application works without problems, only that from the browser, next js gives me this message of 3 serious errors, related to hydration and components! Message:
There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

This question is similar to: Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
